# Fix maven JSTL 1.2.1 dependency so maven-war-plugin doesn't package JARs that offend Tomcat 7

Tags: java, maven, jstl, war

My setup: jdk 7, Tomcat 7.0.29, ,Eclipse Juno (with m2e[Maven 3.0.4 embedded], m2eclipse-wtp)

I have a Dynamic Web Project with this [JSTL](http://jstl.java.net/download.html) dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

When I `mvn package` and deploy on Tomcat, I get these non-fatal messages in the log that don't stop my app from deploying:

```
validateJarFile(...\WEB-INF\lib\jsp-api-2.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
validateJarFile(...\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

I check and yes, JARs in question are being packaged in the WAR. I check the dependencies with `mvn dependency:tree` and get this:

```
[INFO] \- org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO]    \- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jstl-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]       +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO]       \- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:compile
```

Both JARs are showing in the `compile` scope, But if I check the [pom.xml](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/glassfish/web/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/1.2.1/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.pom) on `org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:jar:1.2.1` I see this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

that shows them on the `provided` scope, which I thought would exclude them from the packaging.

**Questions:**

1. How do I tell the WAR plugin to not include these JAR's? `<excludes/>` won't cut it because this also removes them from the build path.
2. What if I want to develop against the Servlet 3.0 spec but keeping this JSTL version?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, the jsp-api was sneaking into the WEB-INF\lib as a transative dependency of the jstl, the fix is to exclude like so.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>${javax.jstl.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am interested in 1.2.1 - this was adding jstl-api as a transitive dependency - which added jsp-api. See my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24468573/281545

Comment: Also your answer reminds me of: http://www.murraywilliams.com/2011/11/running-jstl-1-2-on-tomcat-7-using-maven/

Answer (score 1):

For version ***1.2.1*** [use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468573/281545):

```
<!-- add the selvlet-api that tomcat provides as provided -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <exclusions>
         <!-- jstl-api was adding selvlet-api 2.5 and jsp-api-->
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Because if not the jstl-api ***1.2*** will be added as a dependency. It is the jstl-api that added the jsp-api and servlet-api dependencies.